# Fetching from Cache not working with Service Worker

Tags: javascript, service-worker

I was going through the [Using Service Workers walk-through on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Service_Worker_API/Using_Service_Workers) but made a modification to the Install event that has prevented `caches.match(event.request)`, in the Fetch event, from finding my cached assets.

Here is how the walk-through code looks when you are setting up the Install event to cache your assets:

```
this.addEventListener('install', function(event) {
  event.waitUntil(
    caches.open('v1').then(function(cache) {
      return cache.addAll([
        '/sw-test/',
        '/sw-test/index.html',
        '/sw-test/style.css',
        '/sw-test/app.js',
        '/sw-test/image-list.js',
        '/sw-test/star-wars-logo.jpg',
        '/sw-test/gallery/',
        '/sw-test/gallery/bountyHunters.jpg',
        '/sw-test/gallery/myLittleVader.jpg',
        '/sw-test/gallery/snowTroopers.jpg'
      ]);
    })
  );
});
```

Here is the same code with my minor modification (The key difference is I have remove `'/sw-test/',` from the array being passed into addAll()):

```
this.addEventListener('install', function(event) {
  event.waitUntil(
    caches.open('v1').then(function(cache) {
      return cache.addAll([
        '/sw-test/index.html',
        '/sw-test/style.css',
        '/sw-test/app.js',
        '/sw-test/image-list.js',
        '/sw-test/star-wars-logo.jpg',
        '/sw-test/gallery/',
        '/sw-test/gallery/bountyHunters.jpg',
        '/sw-test/gallery/myLittleVader.jpg',
        '/sw-test/gallery/snowTroopers.jpg'
      ]);
    })
  );
});
```

The next step in the walk-through is to fetch those cached assets.  See the code below:

```
this.addEventListener('fetch', function(event) {
  event.respondWith(
    caches.match(event.request);
  );
});
```

**My question is, why do you need to add `'/sw-test/',` in order for the Fetch event to be able to pull my assets from Cache?  Specifically, why will this line of code `caches.match(event.request);` in the Fetch event not work unless I put `'/sw-test/',` in the array of assets to be cached?**

Also, just as an FYI, I have verified that the assets are in the Cache with both code examples.